# Find list value against certain key in Dictionary

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a dictionary with int and List(of Type) , How can i check if certain key contains certain list value in dictionary.

I have a value and a key and i want to check if value exists that key.

So in following dictionary, Key 1 and value Result_3 should return true

```
  Dim d as new dictionary(of int32, list(of Type)) 

    d.Add(1,
        New List(Of Type)(New Type() _
                            {GetType(Result_1),
                                GetType(Result_2),
                                GetType(Result_3),
                                GetType(Result_4)}))

    d.Add(2,
        New List(Of Type)(New Type() _
                            {GetType(Result_5),
                                GetType(Result_6)}))

    d.Add(3,
        New List(Of Type)(New Type() _
                            {GetType(Result_7)}))
```

I have tried this so far but no luck;

```
     if  d.Where(function(o) o.Value.Contains(GetType(Result_2)) ).Select(Function(n) n.Key = 1)  then

     End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this function

```
Function Check(key as int, value as Type) As Boolean

Return d(key).Contains(value) 

End Function
```

And your example would be

```
If Check(1,GetType(Result_3)) Then...
```

Comment: just found this d.FirstOrDefault(function(o) o.Value.Contains(t)).Key which i believe does the same thing

Comment: You should ask if it is not null instead getting the key because he wants to return Boolean